# How do i Add Dynamic Id's and Extract them at run time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting a result from data base and based on the result i am creating Dynamic list

```
$.each(resultpost, function (i, data) {
    $(".myblogs ul").append('<li><a href="#" id=' + data.PId + '>' + data.Title + '</a></li>');
});
```

My list is being created but what do i do, when i click on one of the links to precisely know which link was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : register click event handler for generated links and check id

```
$(".myblogs ul").on("click","li a", function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a delegated click handler to a parent element, then use `this` within that handler to reference the element which was clicked. Try this:

```
$('.myblogs ul').on('click', 'li a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link being followed (optional)
    alert(this.id); // shows the id of the clicked li element
});
```

Adding incremental `id` attributes is a pain, leads to maintenance issues and is best avoided where possible.